# IIS 7 + Domains and Sub Domains

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, iis-7

I have setup 1 Domain and 1 Sub domain in IIS 7 - Set the bindings/ports etc

When I browse to the subdomain url I get the website of the main domain.  I have not configured an A record for the subdomain.  Is this the problem?

Its the same if I browe the non www version it rewrites or redirects to the www version.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this was because there was a redirect on the top node "Sites" in IIS.  All sorted.

Comment: Glad you resolved [or created a work around for] this issue. Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.